# How can I set elements in the same line vertically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    this.iid = setTimeout(function() {
      var tag_name = self.text(),
          top      = self.position().top + self.outerHeight(true),
          left     = self.position().left;
      $('body').append("<div class='tag_info'>Some explanations about "+tag_name+"</div>");
      $(".tag_info").css({top: top + "px", right: left + "px"}).fadeIn(200);   
    }, 525);
  }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
    if(this.iid){
      clearTimeout(this.iid)
      $('.tag_info').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
    body{
      padding: 20px;
      direction: rtl;
    }

    a {
        color: #3e6d8e !important;
        background-color: #E1ECF4;
        padding: 2px 5px;
    }
    .tag_info{
      position: absolute;
      width: 130px;
      height: 100px;
      display:none;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a>long-length-tag</a>
    <a>tag</a>
```

As you see, that popup is far away than hovered element. While I expect they be in the same line *(vertically)* on the **right** side.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    this.iid = setTimeout(function() {
      var tag_name = self.text(),
          top      = self.position().top + self.outerHeight(true),
          right     = self.position().right; // Update this
      $('body').append("<div class='tag_info'>Some explanations about "+tag_name+"</div>");
      $(".tag_info").css({top: top + "px", right: right + "px"}).fadeIn(200);   
    }, 525);
  }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
    if(this.iid){
      clearTimeout(this.iid)
      $('.tag_info').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

Update your left variable with the example code

It was `left = self.position().left;` Update that to `right = self.position().right;`

and also this variable too

```
$(".tag_info").css({top: top + "px", right: left + "px"}).fadeIn(200);
```

to

```
$(".tag_info").css({top: top + "px", right: right + "px"}).fadeIn(200);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    this.iid = setTimeout(function() {
      var tag_name = self.text(),
          top      = self.position().top + self.outerHeight(true),
          rightside    = self.right();
      $('body').append("<div class='tag_info'>Some explanations about "+tag_name+"</div>");
      $(".tag_info").css({top: top + "px", right: rightside + "px"}).fadeIn(200);   
    }, 525);
  }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
    if(this.iid){
      clearTimeout(this.iid)
      $('.tag_info').remove();
    }
  });
});
$.fn.right = function() {
  return $(document).width() - (this.offset().left +      this.outerWidth());
}
```

```css
body{
      padding: 20px;
      direction: rtl;
    }

    a {
        color: #3e6d8e !important;
        background-color: #E1ECF4;
        padding: 2px 5px;
    }
    .tag_info{
      position: absolute;
      width: 130px;
      height: 100px;
      display:none;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a>long-length-tag</a>
    <a>tag</a>
```

**EDIT**

Add this new function

```
$.fn.right = function() {
   return $(document).width() - (this.offset().left + this.outerWidth());
}
```

And Update this Line

```
right = self.position().right;
```

to

```
right = self.right();
```

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: [Still they aren't in the same line *(right side perspective)*](https://jsfiddle.net/uz6y3L2y/5/)

Comment: Look, in your case, that popup has always `right: 0;` position. Since `right` variable is undefined. The expected result is a dynamic right position based on the hovered tag's position.

Comment: @stack I just update my answer and snippet also please check it hope now it will helps you

Comment: Just for my information. Does `$.fn.right` make a function (named `right`) in jQuery? Isn't there any other approach?

Comment: No it's not any other approach, it's a normal function like `javascript` user defined function

Answer (score 0):

change `left = self.position().left;` to `right = self.position().right;`

change "left" into "right " in css.

```
$(".tag_info").css({top: top + "px", right: right + "px"}).fadeIn(200);
```